# Compatibility Asus prime b360m-k and Ubuntu 18.04 plasma

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, asus, hardware-certification

Please, where I can check compatibility between Ubuntu 18.04 Plasma and Asus prime b360m-k motherboard?

I searched in Google and read several webpages, but I can't confirm this compatibility.

This is the best obtained result in my search:

https://dlcdnimgs.asus.com/websites/global/aboutASUS/OS/Linux-Status-report_20180705.pdf

but prime b360m-k is N/A.

¿Someone has tested this Ubuntu version with this motherboard?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer myself. I have found the answer in linux-hardware.org:

https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=board:asustek-prime-b360m-k-rev-x-0x

Asus prime b360m-k works fine with Ubuntu 18.04 according with this results: https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=board:asustek-prime-b360m-k-rev-x-0x&hwid=44c6c2af3c49

I put the answer here, perhaps it is useful to other users.